# Trying to get property 'price' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 to develop my project and in this project, I want to check if the Cart Price of user is more than a custom number (which should be get from the DB as well), then print `Your delivery is free`.

So in order to do that, I have added this:

```
@foreach(\App\Shop\ProductDelivery::find(1) as $delivery)
    @if($cartPrice >= $delivery->price)
        <i>
        You delivery is free
        </i>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

But it shows me this error:

**Trying to get property 'price' of non-object**

Referring to this line:

```
<?php if($cartPrice >= $delivery->price): ?>
```

However the price already exists in the DB:

[image]

So what is going wrong here ? How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\App\Shop\ProductDelivery::find(1)` just return one record so using foreach in this case will cause your problem. To solve  it, you can change your code to:

```
@php
  $delivery = \App\Shop\ProductDelivery::find(1)
@endphp
@if($delivery && $cartPrice >= $delivery->price)
    <i>
    You delivery is free
    </i>
@endif
```

Or if you still want to use foreach although it's not necessary:

```
@foreach(\App\Shop\ProductDelivery::where('id', 1)->get() as $delivery)
  @if($cartPrice >= $delivery->price)
    <i>
    You delivery is free
    </i>
  @endif
@endforeach
```